# Binding UserControl Property to an INotifyPropertyChanged View Model

Tags: .net, wpf

The example given here is a simplification of the actual UserControl that I am trying to implement but it illustrates the structure and suffers from the same problem. The user control has a DependencyProperty Words that sets the text of textblock that is defined in the user control XAML.

```
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty WordsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Words", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl));
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string Words
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(WordsProperty); }
            set
            {
                m_TextBlock.Text = value;
                SetValue(WordsProperty, value);
            }
```

An INotifyPropertyChanged ViewModelBase class derived ViewModel is assigned to the mainWindow DataContext. The ModelText property set calls OnPropertyChanged.

```
class MainWindow : ViewModelBase
{
    private string m_ModelString;
    public string ModelText
    {
        get { return m_ModelString; }
        set
        {
            m_ModelString = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("ModelText");
        }
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow XAML binding is made to the UserControl and a TextBlock

```
 <Window x:Class="Binding.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="218" Width="266" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Binding.View">
    <Grid>
        <my:MyControl Words="{Binding ModelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,29,0,0" x:Name="myControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="69" Width="179" Background="#FF96FF96" />
        <TextBlock Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="59,116,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding ModelText}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" Background="Yellow" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The binding works for the textblock but not for the user control. Why can't UserControl DependencyProperty be bound in the same way as Control Properties?

Comment: You need to format the code block with the {}

Comment: I did try to use {} but obviously I did it wrong. Sorry about that it was my first attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
m_TextBlock.Text = value;
```

WPF does not directly use properties backed by a DP.

If you want to update `m_TextBlock.Text` when the `WordsProperty` is modified, either bind that textblock to `Words`, or use the `PropertyChangedCallback` in `UIPropertyMetadata`:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty WordsProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("Words", 
                                    typeof(string), 
                                    typeof(MyControl),
                                    new UIPRopertyMetadata(
                 new PropertyChangedCallback(
                     (dpo, dpce) => 
                     {
                         //Probably going to need to first cast dpo to MyControl
                         //And then assign its m_TextBlock property's text.
                         m_TextBlock.Text = dpce.NewValue as string;
                     })));
```

Consider `dpo` the sender, and `dpce` the event args.

Comment: Thanks I tried the PropertyChangedCallback and it works perfectly.

Comment: @user1683083 Please consider accepting this answer then ;) (click the tick at the top left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should to assign the text to your UserControl's textbox by a binding and not by `m_TextBlock.Text = value;`.

Maybe you could user a binding like this in your UserControl Xaml:

```
    Text="{Binding Words
, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Comment: I can see your point in the case of the example I gave. The actual user control that I want to implement is more complicated though. It uses a canvas to render a foreground bitmap over a background bitmap using translation and rotation transforms, but the transform coordinates come from the model. I planned to add a dependency property to the user control to allow the model to notify the user control by supplying a class containing x,y,theta then use this data to modify the transforms, but I can't get the binding to work.

Comment: I think the better idea could be to set x,y,theta properties as DependencyProperties in the user control, and then make bindings in the view model to them. Then (like Baboon said) you can to subscribe to the dependency property's OnPropertyChange callback.

Comment: My idea is that you can also use bindings to the same user control's dependency properties in this one's view (xaml).

Comment: Yes, that sound a better approach to build a view model for the user control and bind each property separately rather than coding the view.